# py2exe adding binary dependencies for random numpy and scipy libraries

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, py2exe

I am creating an executable for my Tkinter application using py2exe. It works perfectly on my computer (Windows 7 x64). However, when running on another Windows 7 64-bit compupter, the executable does not work. I am assuming it does not because of the following:
http://imageshack.com/a/img35/718/mcl4.png
It seems as though some of the numpy and scipy libraries are being added to the binary dependencies, even though I do not use those libraries in my application at all. I tried adding those to my includes option in my setup.py file, but it still adds it to the binary dependencies. I'm pretty certain this is the reason for the exe not working on other computers. Here is my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob
import matplotlib

data_files = [('Microsoft.VC90.CRT', glob(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*'))]
data_files.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())

setup(
    data_files = data_files,
    console = ['GUI.py'],
    zipfile = None,
    options = {
           'py2exe': {
                      'includes': ['Tkinter', 'rpy2.robjects', 'numpy', 'numpy.fft.fftpack_lite', 'numpy.linalg._umath_linalg', 'scipy.integrate._quadpack', 'scipy.interpolate.dfitpack', 
                                   'scipy.optimize.minpack2', 'pandas', 'collections', 'datetime', 'time'],
                      'bundle_files': 3, 
                      'compressed': True,
                      'optimize': 2,
                      'dll_excludes': ['MSVCP90.dll', 'tcl85.dll', 'tk85.dll']
            }
    }
)
```

Any workarounds for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you use matplotlib, numpy is a dependency ( http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html). Do you see all the pyd files in your dist folder as expected? If not, what happens if you manually copy them?

Comment: So essentially what I ended up doing was just excluding those files in the dll_excludes option. Everything works fine, but I assume I could also just copy paste those files into the dist folder as well, as as you said they were not in the folder originally.